# RegEx Positive Look ahead need variable number in the middle

Tags: regex

I have a string of data that looks like this.

```
10002_*:*_2_*:*_5794277_*|*_10059_*:*_10_*:*_57016026_*|*_10006_*:*_1_*:*_1872914_*|*_10005_*:*_2_*:*_16176841
```

I am looking to extract the **57016026** but where the **10** is that can be any number 1-999.  When I use this Regular Expression it works for two dig but I need to make it work for one or 3 dig numbers also.

```
(?<=10059_\*:\*_[0-9][0-9]_\*:\*_)[0-9]*
```

I tried the following but it did not work.

```
(?<=10059_\*:\*_[0-9]*_\*:\*_)[0-9]*
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: For what language ?

Comment: Why does it need to be a positive lookbehind? `10059_\*:\*_\d{1,3}_\*:\*_([0-9]*)`

Comment: Your title says lookahead, but the code in the question is a lookbehind.

Comment: @ChrisDoyle I think because the string before it is a fixed length which make it easier for him to distinguish whatever after it.(i.e., before`[0-9]*`)

Comment: @SaSkY, but its not fixed length, the OP says the string can have number between `1-999`

Comment: @ChrisDoyle you are right, my fault. I looked at `5794277` ignoring the desired one `57016026`

Comment: @ChrisDoyle But even if it is not fixed length with some regex flavors like ECMAScript you can make the length non-fixed and ECMAScript and .NET accept that.

Comment: It does not need to be lookbehind if there is a better way.  I am using thies expression inside of a Google Looker field  to extract out a value making a custom column.  I want to extract the time which is represented in that position of the data following the status code.  

In the example I posted there are 4 status codes groups separated by _*|*_ and then each group has three pieces of data separated by _*:*_ 
Status code, Count of times in that code, duration of time in that code.

Strange it is a pipe between the stars above it is typed that way but its showing as a /

Comment: @SaSkY - The expression will be inside a data set that refreshes daily.  I plan to use it to create columns for count and time for each status code present in that row.  They can appear in any order which is why I can not do a simple parse of text to columns.

Comment: @JimByers which one of these values changes and is not a fixed value `_10059_`, `_57016026_`

Comment: @JimByers Is the length of `10` inside the string `_10_`  can be changed to be 3 digit in length maximum ? it means the max number is `999` not `1000` or above ? Am I right ?

Comment: @SaSkY the fixed value is 10059 and the max length would be 999. In most cases it is not going to exceed 99 just preparing just in case.

Comment: Which regex flavor are you going to use ? ECMAScript(javascript), python, .NET, (PCRE)PHP ?

Comment: @SaSkY according to the website "Looker Studio uses the RE2 expression syntax"